# How to attach a large pdf file to a crm dynamics email using a post rest call?

Tags: java, rest, post, dynamics-crm, email-attachments

I am able to make a post request for an email attachment successfully only when my file contents less than 100 characters. For the same code when I post a large file content  such 1Mb  I get a dynamics error

```
public enum Payload {
        PAGING_COOKIE("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie"),
        CONTEXT("@odata.contex"),
        ETAG("@odata.etag"),
        ID("@odata.id"),
        BIND("@odata.bind"),
        VALUE("value"),
        COUNT("@odata.count"),
        NEXT_LINK("@odata.nextLink"),
        NAVIGATION("_"),
        ERROR("error"),
        MESSAGE("message"),
        INNER_ERROR("innererror"),
        CODE("code"),
        TYPE("type"),
        STACK_TRACE("stacktrace");
        ....
}

@Stateless
public class ActivityMimeAttachmentRepository extends DynamicsRepository {

    // Select
    private static final String SELECT_GUID = "$select=" + ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields.activitymimeattachmentid.name();

    @Inject
    private ActivityMimeAttachmentBuilder activityMimeAttachmentBuilder;


    public void createAttachement(ActivityMimeAttachmentBean attachment) throws DynamicsException {

        String url = activityMimeAttachmentBuilder.url(ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.RESOURCE_NAME, null, null, true);

        // Construction des propriétés à créer
        ArrayList<ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields> crmFields = new ArrayList<ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields>();

        crmFields.add(ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields.filename);
        crmFields.add(ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields.mimetype);
        crmFields.add(ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields.body);
        crmFields.add(ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields.subject);
        crmFields.add(ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields.objectid);
        crmFields.add(ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields.objecttypecode);

        // Construction du payload
        String payload = activityMimeAttachmentBuilder.build(false, attachment, crmFields.toArray(new ActivityMimeAttachmentBean.CrmFields[0])).toString();

        // Création dans Dynamics CRM
        super.create(url, payload, Header.RETURN_REPRESENTATION);
    }
}

public JSONObject create(String url, String payload, Header...headers) throws DynamicsException {
        WebClient webClient = build(url, false, authenticationService.getToken(false), null, headers);
        Response response = webClient.post(payload);

        if (401 == response.getStatus()) {
            webClient = build(url, false, authenticationService.getToken(true), null, headers);
            response = webClient.post(payload);
        }

        JSONObject entity = build(webClient, "POST", payload, response);
        return entity;
    }
```

The error I am getting is : 
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object., type: System.NullReferenceException, stacktrace:    at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EdmTypeConverte
r.ConvertToCrmEntity(EdmEntityObject edmEntity, EntityReference entityReference, IEdmModel edmModel)
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.CreateEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, EdmEntityObject entityObject, Boolean isUpsert)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PostEntitySetImplementation(String& entitySetName, EdmEntityObject entityObject)
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )

When I reduce the body content to less than 100 characters i do not get this error and the file are attached to the email.

Comment: Kindly post the error that you are getting.

Comment: Can you show the payload ? Are you encoding the body properly ?